# Preparing Ubuntu MATE for ramboot / no networking questions

Tags: ram, lan, ubuntu-mate

Recently I've successfully made Ubuntu 16.04 run from RAM entirely as [shown here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4lbiJ8iarUT1JDVTBYT1ZPVE0/view?usp=sharing). It's insanely fast :) I have only 8GB of DDR3 @ 1866MHz.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

But that was a clean installation before I've installed updates, and my frequently used programs, which made it way too big to be loaded to RAM, and even if I could, I would still need 3GB free RAM for rendering with Blender, so there was no way I could use that efficiently.

Since then in the BIOS I've changed the shared 1GB of RAM that was set for the integrated graphics to only 32MB, as Blender can only use my CPU anyway (because it does not support Radeon graphics). That gave me +1GB, and decided to use Ubuntu MATE 17.04 (because it's lighter both in memory usage, and in size, while still user friendly) I've installed my programs, updated it, and removed some other programs that I don't really use, making [this script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4lbiJ8iarUd0V2aEo1anVrMlE/view?usp=sharing) to automate the process. Now it's about 4.4GB (about as big as Ubuntu 16.04 was when I did that) with everything except Blender installed (I'm using a modified portable version of Blender 2.78).

The first question is, how could I make Ubuntu MATE even lighter, while still keeping its user friendly aspect?

After I ran my script, the network icon from the upper panel disappeared, and the network (LAN) isn't working. Can someone analyze the script and tell me which program I've removed could have done that? I need the LAN.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but you're going to have to install Ubuntu MATE 16.04 to prevent this question from being closed because questions about development versions of Ubuntu are off topic.

Comment: LAN issue solved... network manager was removed with the bluetooth stuff I removed... It works now...